# fire event on pivot sync in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a pivot model

```
class UserRoles extends Pivot
{
    protected $table="user_roles";
}
```

i am using syncWithoutDetaching to update the pivot table

```
     $user->roles()
          ->syncWithoutDetaching(
          [ $roleId => [ 'is_active' => $value]]
      );
```

the relation roles() is already using the pivot model class and i created an observer in order to detect the updated event on the pivot model

```
class UserRolesObserver
{
 
    public function created()
    {
        Log::info("event fired");
    }

    public function updated()
    {
        Log::info("event fired");
    }

    public function saved()
    {
        Log::info("event fired");
    }
```

the observer's updated event isn't being fired even when the update is done

Answer (score 1):

Pivot tables do not fire events. You would need to utilize a package like this one to fire pivot events: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-pivot-events.

Once you install that package you can utilize `pivotAttaching` and `pivotAttached` methods on the Observer.